# Prove that $\vdash \phi \land \psi \leftrightarrow \psi \land \phi$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to show that $\vdash \phi \land \psi \leftrightarrow \psi \land \phi$ for any two formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$. Before I write down my thoughts, I would like to mention that I am by no means experienced with logic, so if I should mention what axioms I am assuming or anything else, please let me know (I remember the prof only saying that we are using a Hilbert deduction system and the deduction rule is modus ponens; I will also mention that this is an introductory logic course).

The exercise previously asked me to show the following four facts:
$$\{\phi \land \psi\} \vdash \phi$$
$$\{\phi \land \psi\} \vdash \psi$$
$$\{\phi, \psi\} \vdash \phi \land \psi$$
$$\{\phi, \psi\} \vdash \chi \text{ iff } \{ \phi \land \psi\}\vdash \chi \text{ for any formula }\chi$$
This is why I thought that some of them may come in handy. If I write the definition of $\leftrightarrow$ in terms of $\land$ and $\rightarrow$, I will end up with a horrendous expression, so this doesn't look like the way to go. I thought that I might use the completeness theorem and this is a valid way to solve the problem, but I think that I am supposed to solve it using syntactic results only.

EDIT: As requested, the axioms are:
$\bullet$ $\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \phi)$
$\bullet$ $(\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \chi)) \rightarrow ((\phi \rightarrow \psi)\rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \chi))$
$\bullet$ $(\neg \psi \rightarrow \neg \phi) \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$,
where $\phi$, $\psi$ and $\chi$ are formulas.

Comment: You have to write the axioms of the system... In [some cases](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#IntFirOrdPreLog) $(A \land B) \to A$ is an axiom.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ok, I will add the axioms right away

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have added the axioms of the system. If I should specify anything else, please let me know, thank you!

Comment: If those are the axioms, maybe $\land$ is an abbreviation... $\lnot (\phi \to \lnot \psi)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yes, this is how $\land$ is defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have proved, $\{\phi,\psi\}\vdash\psi\land\phi$ (since $\{\phi,\psi\}=\{\psi,\phi\}$ and according to point 3 of your exercise). And according to point 4 this means that $\{\phi\land\psi\}\vdash\psi\land\phi$. Using the deduction theorem we gain $\vdash(\phi\land\psi)\rightarrow(\psi\land\phi).$ Similarly, $\vdash(\psi\land\phi)\rightarrow(\phi\land\psi)$.

Now it's quite simple to conclude $\vdash(\phi\land\psi)\leftrightarrow(\psi\land\phi).$

Comment: Niktin thank you! Could you tell me how I may conclude that $\vdash(\phi\land\psi)\leftrightarrow(\psi\land\phi)$? I mean, this is really intuitive, but I want to see what the formal reasoning would be.

Comment: The formal proof depends on the exact definition of equivalence in this axiomatization. For instance, if $\alpha\leftrightarrow\beta$ is an abbreviation for $(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\land(\beta\rightarrow\alpha)$ then the desired formula is an immediate consequence of what we know and from point 3 from the exersize you've mentioned.

Comment: Yes, this is the case. Thank you!